# Spring Integration Re-Processing Messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am building an application for work using Spring Integration, and I am completely new to the framework.

I am using an idempotent receiver to check a database to see if I have seen the ID of a message before, and if I have, the message gets passed to an aggregator. Once the message has been aggregated a new message is sent to the following handler.

The issue I am seeing is when the message fails in the handler, it seems to get re-queued somehow. What I see in the logs is the idempotent receiver will drop messages it has seen, pass a message along it hasn't to the aggregator, and that message will fail. The next cycle the idempotent receiver will drop the message that had failed before. The cycle after that, the idempotent receiver will pass the message along, and it will fail again causing the cycle to start over.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean and what you expect. First of all a purpose of [Idempotent Received](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver) do not process the same message again. According your description you expect something opposite:

> The logic of the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` is based on the provided `MessageSelector` and, if the message isn’t accepted by that selector, it will be enriched with the `duplicateMessage` header set to true. The target `MessageHandler` (or downstream flow) can consult this header to implement the correct idempotency logic. If the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` is configured with a `discardChannel` and/or `throwExceptionOnRejection = true`, the *duplicate* Message won’t be sent to the target `MessageHandler.handleMessage()`, but discarded.

The very important word there is `duplicate`. So, please, reconsider your treatment for the Idempotent Receiver.

What you describer further with the failure, re-queuing and reprocessing sounds for me like transaction rollback. And that's also true if you use `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor` based on the `JdbcMetadataStoreTests` and all the data stored during roll backed TX will be dropped because no commit.

That might be easier for us to help you if you share a simple Spring Boot application on GitHub to let us to reproduce and understand better what's going on. Otherwise your question isn't clear and becomes a good candidate to be closed here by StackOverflow policies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to get a simple example set up to post.